# How do I rotate sprites on a perimeter of a circle towards the center?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, geometry

I have *n* sprites on the perimeter of a circle:

```
let radius = 100
let n = 10

let parentNode = SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.yellowColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(radius), CGFloat(radius)))
parentNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
parentNode.zPosition = 1.5

for sprite in 0...n {
    let aSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image.png")
    aSprite.setScale(0.15)
    aSprite.name = "sprite"+String(sprite)

    let theta = Float(Double(sprite) * ((2 * M_PI)/n))
    let x = radius * Double(cosf(theta))
    let y = radius * Double(sinf(theta))

    aSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y))

    parentNode.addChild(aSprite)
}
```

I want to rotate each sprite towards the center of the circle:

```
CGPoint(CGRectGetMidX(parentNode.frame),CGRectGetMidY(parentNode.frame))
```

I tried using `atan2` to accomplish this, but it didn't work:

```
aSprite.zRotation = atan2(CGRectGetMidY(parentNode.frame)-aSprite.position.y, CGRectGetMidX(parentNode.frame) - aSprite.position.x)
```

Comment: Rotate by (-theta) ?

Comment: Would you like to it to swirl towards the center or just rotate while moving towards the center?

Comment: It doesn't move. I want it to spawn facing te center

Comment: The `zRotation` calculation is correct if your image faces to the right when the angle = 0. If it faces up (when angle = 0), you'll need to subtract CGFloat(M_PI_2) to the `zRotation`.